# SQL Query values change when I join another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, sum

So I am trying to look into inventory turnover on a small company's database. What I essentially am doing is taking the Items table and joining it to the POLineItemReceipts table, then I am joining the Items table to the SalesTransactionLineItems table and trying to find out how many of each item I have purchased (in POLineItemReceipts) and how many I have sold (in SalesTransactionLineItems) then dividing those two numbers to see what my turnover is.

My query works with each individual table, the SalesTransactionLineItems and POLineItemReceipts, but when I try to integrate both tables into one query, it gives random weird numbers for my SUM(Quantity) columns. There is a SUM for both the POLineItemReceipts and  SalesTransactionLineItems tables because they both have a quantity column.

I suspect my joins are throwing everything off, but I'm not really sure.

Here are my separate queries

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Item_PK
    ,i.Code
    ,SUM(p.Quantity) as Y
FROM POLineItemReceipts p JOIN Items i ON i.Item_PK = p.Item_FK
GROUP BY  i.Item_PK, i.Code
ORDER BY i.Item_PK
```

[image]

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Item_PK
    ,i.Code
    ,SUM(p.Quantity) as Y
FROM SalesTransactionLineItems p JOIN Items i ON i.Item_PK = p.Item_FK
GROUP BY  i.Item_PK, i.Code
ORDER BY i.Item_PK
```

[image]

and then combined

```
SELECT  DISTINCT i.Item_PK              
                    ,i.Code                 AS         Code
                    ,SUM(pr.Quantity)       AS TotalPurchased_X
                    ,SUM(tl.Quantity)       AS TotalSold_Y

    FROM
                    Items i JOIN POLineItemReceipts pr ON i.Item_PK = pr.Item_FK
                    JOIN SalesTransactionLineItems tl ON i.Item_PK = tl.Item_FK
    WHERE
                    i.ItemType_FK = 1
    GROUP BY
                    i.Item_PK
                    ,i.Code

    ORDER BY
                    i.Item_PK ASC
```

[image]

Pay special attention to Item_PK 2 and 3 (Y is totalsold and X is totalpurchased. I ran the query with different headers in SQL server)

Not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: When you "combined" you queries you added extra `GROUP BY` fields. They control what is being aggregated.

Comment: Can you set-up [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) to show your problem?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm not sure what you mean. I took out the extra fields other than i.Item_PK and then removed the others from the group by as well and got the same incorrect results.

Comment: @PM77-1 also, I will try. Not sure how to though

Comment: Neither of the original queries groups by `i.description` and `i.Qty_Comp_OnHand`.  You also have a `WHERE` filter that was not present in either of the original queries.  I'm just pointing out that you did more than simply combining two queries.

Comment: Alternatively you can post sample data and the expected result. It will be very helpful in analyzing your situation.

Comment: After removing those the error still persists. I will post expected result

Comment: What is the relationship between the tables?  You use `INNER JOIN`s that filter out any records that does not have matching counterparts.  Could this be an issue?

Comment: @PM77-1 I have used almost every type of join possible... I've done INNER JOIN, I've used OUTER JOIN and LEFT OUTER JOIN and it continues on... The tables in this database are not directly related, as in there are no real foreign keys. Instead, they just mark certain columns with PK and FK, like Item_PK in the Items table and Item_FK in the POLineItemReceipts and SalesTransactionLineItems tables. Not sure if I need to relate all of these together a different way. For POLineItemReceipts I could go through Items, ItemVendors, PO, POLineItems, and POLineItemReceipts...

Answer (score 0):

For the combined case, you have grouped by with extra i.Description            ,i.Qty_Comp_OnHand. what does it return if you do :

```
SELECT  DISTINCT i.Item_PK              AS ID
                ,i.Code                 AS         Code                    
                ,SUM(pr.Quantity)       AS         TotalPurchased
                ,SUM(tl.Quantity)       AS         TotalSold
                ,(SUM(tl.Quantity)/SUM(pr.Quantity)) AS Turnover
FROM
                Items i JOIN POLineItemReceipts pr ON i.Item_PK = pr.Item_FK
                JOIN SalesTransactionLineItems tl ON i.Item_PK = tl.Item_FK
WHERE
                i.ItemType_FK = 1
GROUP BY
                i.Item_PK
                ,i.Code

ORDER BY
                ID ASC
```

Comment: The issue persists. Posting data now for analysis